# No way to view CV from careers.stackoverflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

After some updates of the resource I am unable to head to my CV page from the careers main page. Now it just redirects me to the [employer page](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/user-dashboard/346111) but I am not an employer. Also, I can't find any way to get to the CV from this page, there are no such buttons or links. The only way I may go to my CV is by manually editing the web-address to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv which is not a human-oriented way of doing this.

Comment: I think you're meant to be on the [Jobs page](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs), careers seems to be for the employers

Comment: @Draken excuse me, I'll try to explain again - when recently used `careers.stackoverflow.com` it had a button "CV" which was pointed to such a page. Now there are no such buttons and more - there is no such main page anymore, when I try to open this page it redirects me right to `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/user-dashboard/346111` but I don't need this. It would be okay but I am not an employer and more, there is no way to go to CV page anymore. `Jobs` page has such button yes, but last time I used `careers` it had it too. So do I always need now to go to `/jobs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Careers site is now for employers only. The candidate side of things has moved to [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs).

You now access your CV at https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/