# Where'd my SO Careers "current community" link go?

Tags: support

I loved this shortcut! ([screengrab: Background text bleeds though into dropdown menu on employer page of Stackoverflow careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251719/background-text-bleeds-though-into-dropdown-menu-on-employer-page-of-stackoverfl/251723))

[image]

And now it's gone? Can't think of anything I have changed setting-wise

[image]

Is this gone for good? Bug? Coming back? Why!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Stack Overflow Careers" is now "Stack Overflow Jobs" and has a button on the main Stack Overflow site:

[image: Jobs Button]

The old careers site is still up, but is [now employer only.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329784/2607247) Your CV and other items from Careers are now on Jobs.

As Jobs is now part of the main site, not on its own separate site, it's unlikely that it will be readded like that to the site selector.

Comment: ahh I see. Eh, unsure how I'm feeling with that flow - but careers has seemed to always be on the chopping block so I suppose it was just the for the branch to finally snap. Thanks for the answer! Hey what do you mean by "employer only" now?

Comment: The old careers site no longer has your CV or anything like that- It's a portal for employers as far as I'm aware. I'm looking for a source on that part, as I know it's been said before. Jobs appears to be getting a _lot_ more attention developer wise since it moved to SO, so it might be good it's fully here now.

Comment: Careers hasn't been killed, @scniro - just renamed and integrated into the rest of Stack Overflow (well, sorta - work is still ongoing). The old URL now goes to the employer side of things, where you can buy job listings and so on.

Comment: @Shog9 nice to hear, actually pretty stoked for a single sign on way to get to it all finally